# How to slice string from the end in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of binary values as strings with different lengths, however I need to slice off the last 18 characters from each value. So in the examples below, the bold is what needs to be kept.

**11001**000000000000001010

**110**000000001101011100

What would be the way to do this using JavaScript?

Comment: what exactly about [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) do you not understand?

Comment: What do you want to do if the binary value is less than 18 characters

Comment: @nivas none of the values I have are less than 18 so it won't be an issue.

Comment: You could use `str.substr(0, str.length - 18);` which is clearer!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You have to use negative index in `String.prototype.slice()` function.

- using negative index as first argument
  returns the sliced string to the 6 elements counting from the end of the string.

```js
var example = "javascript";
console.log(example.slice(-6));
```

- using negative index as the second argument returns the sliced 
  string from 0 to the 6th element counting from the end. It's opposite to the first method.

```js
var example = "javascript";

console.log(example.slice(0, -6));
```

**In your particular case**, you have to use the second method.

```js
console.log('11001000000000000001010'.slice(0, -18));

console.log('110000000001101011100'.slice(0, -18));
```

If you want to read more about that function, visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: If you're still interessted http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344581/so-should-force-downvoters-to-leave-a-comment