# Get the last two positions of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, position

I would like to know how can I obtain the last two elements of this array like this:

```
array = [1,5,7,8,10,12,23,24];
```

I am trying to obtain with `slice() function` but it doesn´t work for me, beacuse I always I want to obtain the last two positions.

```
array = [23,24];
```

I hope that anyone can help me in this question.

Regards!

Comment: you want last two position OR array value?

Comment: The last two values @RanaGhosh

Comment: @FabianSierra It's the same problem. The number doesn't matter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/slice) with negative index.

```js
var array = [1,5,7,8,10,12,23,24];

console.log(array.slice(-2));
```

You can learn more about this method also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308976/how-to-slice-string-from-the-end-in-javascript/42309034#42309034).

Comment: Just a pointer, next time if you see such a basic question, please look for possible duplicates and close it as duplicate. Its a bad practice to answer a dupe. :-)

Comment: @Rajesh If only I could close the question and mark it as duplicate, I would do it immediately. I just need more rep points to do it.

Comment: You could share dupe as comment so others who have reps could close it.

Comment: @Rajesh Right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
array = [1,5,7,8,10,12,23,24];


console.log(array.slice(-2))
```

Use slice -2

Comment: @Rajesh it was a typo

Comment: Also a minor question, this is a basic question. Did you tried looking for possible duplicates before answering?

Comment: I liked the first edit, I didn't even know you could create a number like that. JS truly is a weird and wonderful language.

Answer (score 0):

[`aray.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) also

**Note:** `Splice` it will update the original array also

```js
var array = [1,5,7,8,10,12,23,24];

console.log(array.splice(-2));
```

Comment: Whats the difference between your answer and other answers? A user with your rep should know to read other answers before posting

Comment: @Rajesh `splice` vs `slice`

Comment: *I am trying to obtain with slice() function* OP is looking for `slice`. Also splice will update original array

Comment: I said `splice` **also** can do this. Yes. it will affect original array also. i will update my content.